# Using webdriver with c# how can I select a drop down item by text if the drop down menu is not a select element?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the following block of code:

```
<div id="rtmenu"><span class="rt-combobox"><input name="" type="text" autocomplete="off" label="" placeholder="" class=""><span class="rt-combobox-button" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">▼</span><div class="menu-vertical" role="menu" aria-haspopup="true" style="-webkit-user-select: none; left: 342px; top: 357px; display: none;"><div class="rt-menuitem" role="menuitem" id=":l" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="rt-menuitem-content">Cars</div></div><div class="rt-menuitem" role="menuitem" id=":m" aria-hidden="false" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="rt-menuitem-content">Motorcycles</div></div></div></span></div>
```

What I would like to do is select the menu items "Cars" and "Motorcycles" by their text (or value).  I can get them easily by xpath or by ID but the trouble is that their ID's change frequently and new items are added to the list so that breaks my xpaths too.

I have tried using "select" but this dropdown menu isn't a select menu in the traditional sense.

Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thanks everyone

p.s I'm using c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with c#, but I can suggest an approach or two.

As it is not the select tag, in all cases you must imitate real user's actions, such as click - wait until options list is displyed - find needed option - click on it

1. You can use xpath locator `.//div[text()='Cars']` to get the required option directly
2. You can iterate through the list of all available options, check if its text equals the needed one and if it is - click the element and break the cycle

You've mentioned that your locators become invalid due to new ID's and items in list, so ypu need to use such locators, that do not depend on ID or indexes in this case. BTW, using indexes in xpath is horrible, IMHO